# How can I determine the edition of Windows NT?

Tags: windows, windows-nt-4

According to wikipedia, there are lots of edition of [Windows NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) - Workstation, Server, Server Enterprise Edition, Terminal Server, Embedded... But how can I determine the edition of Windows NT in my box? The output of "winver" command is like

```
Micsoft(R) Windows NT(R)
Version 4.0 (Build 1381: Service Pack 6)
Copyright (C) 1981-1996 Microsoft Corp.
Revised Service Pack 6a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't it show the edition on the splash screen at bootup as below? (1)

Doesn't it say in the Start Menu as below? (2)

Open the registry and navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, then look for a value called `EditionID`. If it's not there, then there should be another value (probably numeric) that can be looked up to find the edition. Or you can use a [command-line tool](http://jesusnjim.com/code/windows/GetVersionEx.html) to get the OS version info and look up the numbers in the chart. (3)

You could also try the [SPCheck](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279631) tool.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah... a stupid question... Thanks for your answer. :)